# Coupling constant in the Yang-Mills action

Tags: gauge-theory, field-theory, yang-mills

Intuitively, gauge coupling defines the strength of interactions between fields. But how to interpret the coupling $1/g^2$ in front of the kinetic term of Yang-Mills theories, $-\frac{1}{4g^2}tr(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing $F=\mathrm{d}A + A\wedge A$, we have
$$ \frac{1}{g^2}\mathrm{tr}(F\wedge{\star}F) = \frac{1}{4g^2}\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{d}A\wedge{\star}\mathrm{d} A+ \mathrm{d}A\wedge{\star}(A\wedge A) + A\wedge A\wedge{\star}\mathrm{d}A + A\wedge A\wedge{\star}(A \wedge A))$$
and now rescaling the field $A$ as $A\mapsto gA$ gives
$$ \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{d}A\wedge{\star}\mathrm{d} A+g \mathrm{d}A\wedge{\star}(A\wedge A) + gA\wedge A\wedge{\star}\mathrm{d}A + g^2A\wedge A\wedge{\star}(A \wedge A))$$
and this rescaled field is the physical field (since now the kinetic term has no prefactor). You can see that the three-gluon vertices gets a factor of $g$, and the four-gluon vertices gets a factor of $g^2$, so $g$ plays indeed the role of a coupling constant - of the coupling of the gauge field to itself.

Comment: What is the reason to use the form $\frac{1}{g^2}tr(F\wedge *F)$? Is it merely to make S-duality invariance manifest?

Comment: @Kosm: In that form, the gauge covariant derivative is just $\mathrm{d} + A\wedge$ and not $\mathrm{d} + g A\wedge$. Mathematicians prefer not to have a factor in there, while physicists usually prefer to have no $g$ in front of the $\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\mu A_\nu$ part as that's more convenient for deriving Feynman rules (and additionally put factors of $\mathrm{i}$ everywhere as they prefer $A$ to be Hermitian for $\mathrm{SU}(N)$). It's a matter of taste and convention.